# Serbian latin charcters in POST method in PHP script

Tags: php, android, character-encoding

i have a problem inserting Serbian Latin characters from android app in mysql database. Instead of `č, ć, š` it shows `?, ? , ?`.

Manually I can insert these chars in db, but from application I can't.

Any help would be appreciated!

Here is my PHP given

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("xx.xx.xx.xx","xxxx","xxxx","xxxx");
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['NAD']) && isset($_POST['KOM'])&& isset($_POST['VR']) &&     isset($_POST['IDV'])){

$NAD = $_POST['NAD'];
$KOM = $_POST['KOM'];
$IDV = $_POST['IDV'];
$VR = $_POST['VR'];


$result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO komentari(id, ime, komentar,vrijeme) VALUES('$IDV', '$NAD', '$KOM','$VR')");

// check if row inserted or not
if ($result) {        // successfully inserted into database
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // failed to insert row
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Doslo je do greske";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {
// required field is missing
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Nedostaje polje";

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: Your entire rendering pipeline has to be utf-8. web page, client browser -> server, server->php, php->database, database tables/fields, etc... If you're getting `?`, then you've got a character set mismatch somewhere.

Comment: @MarcB I do not know really what could be the problem. Database accepts it when manually insertin ("Insert into T1 values 'ččč'"). But from my app it simply won't work. Application does accept it, because I have printed values in Log_cat.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP shouldn't be the problem. You can try the function `utf8_encode`, but usually it's unnecessary, and it probably won't work. All you need to do is make sure that every single part of your website has the same character encoding, and that the character encoding supports every character that you intend to use.

The usual and easiest way is using UTF-8 (MySQL calls it utf8_unicode_ci, I think), without BOM, as that can occasionally cause problems (some software calls this ANSI as UTF-8). So make sure that every HTML/PHP page, and even your JS and CSS, while you're at it, as well as your whole database structure, is in UTF-8.

If you already have a structure that's too heavy to go around and convert everything, then your only solution is to do it "old-fashioned". Before you save anything into the database, you'll need to encode everything into a very encoding-type-safe form, for example with `htmlentities`.

And then, unless you want to end up with stuff like `&eacute;` in your pages, you need to decode the text to its previous form, using, for example, `htmlentities_decode` (aka `html_entity_decode`, I think both work).

This is a band-aid, however. There are very few valid reasons for not always making sure that everything is in UTF-8 before you start. Always do that in the future.

Comment: I do not know really what could be the problem. Database accepts it when manually insertin ("Insert into T1 values 'ččč'"). But from my app it simply won't work. Application does accept it, because I have printed values in Log_cat.

Comment: When you enter it manually (I guess through PHPMyAdmin), you're using only the database. Unless you were using a charset that simply doesn't have accents, which would be extremely weird, it would work that way, of course. You're entering information in the database, in the database's encoding and your keyboard. Of course it's gonna work. But if your pages don't fit, then the problem appears. And mind you, even if it works one way (DB -> page) it doesn't mean it'll work the other way (page -> DB). Just do as I said and make your character sets fit. I'm sure your issue comes from there.